# Strange behavior with ListView and custom BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I'm having a strange behavior with a custom BaseAdapter.

First of all, I have three colors:

Blue, Dark blue and yellow: [image] [image] [image]

On my custom BaseAdapter, the row I inflate is **always dark blue**, so when I want to change it, I just have to change it when I want.

I want to change it on position 0, 1 and when text is something:

```
            if (position == 0 || position == 1) {
                row.setBackgroundColor(main.getResources().getColor(R.color.azzurro)); // blue (not dark)
            } else if (lista.get(position).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("something")) {
                row.setBackgroundColor(main.getResources().getColor(R.color.gialloBarra)); // yellow
                row.findViewById(R.id.imageView2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                testo.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            }
```

the **strange behavior** is when I click to some item and I do something, when I go back, all my items except the one with the text "something" get blue (not dark blue, even inflating the **dark blue**):

I have Overriden this as well:

```
@Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3;
    }
```

what am I doing bad?

thanks in advance.

---

**ADD**

I'm not using my `convertView`:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = null;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.itembluemarino, parent, false);
```

---

**EDIT!!!**

It's happening also with the whole `FragmentActivity`, I mean, popolating several views (listviews with R.layout.itembluemarino) gets with another color... (My colors are R.color.azzurro and R.color.blueMarino)

Comment: Post your whole adapter code. It's looks like you using convertView, in this case view not inflating. List reuse old view.

Comment: Added, blueMarino means darkBlue